# adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE does nothing?

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging

Upon searching on how to debug sqlite i come across the command
`adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE` 
but it doesn't seems to log any query on my device  `Samgung S4 running CyanogenMod` and also on a `Nexus 4`

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you find a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: Not until the moment

Comment: @forcewill and now?

Answer (score 0):

I always use this:

> adb shell setprop db.log.slow_query_threshold 0

:) Hope it works.